# The Fat Death ?? - book series pre-1982

Tags: story-identification

Between 1978 and 1983, I read three (?) books in a series which described a future world in change. (The books I read were in Danish, translated from English.) The change depended on the location of the suns, and one of the phases or events was referred to in Danish as FAT DEATH. There were probably three phases, each of which triggered different pressures on populations that had to learn to adapt. There might have been different races in each of the phases.

The three books - as I remember - had a colorful front, one was mostly green and another purple. Maybe I was looking at planet from above? Not sure. I think the books were already ten-plus years old in 1982.

It was **not** *[The Faded Sun trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Faded_Sun_Trilogy)* by C. J. Cherryh.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is the [*Helliconia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helliconia) trilogy of novels by Brian W. Aldiss.

> It is an epic chronicling the rise and fall of a civilisation over more than a thousand years as the planet progresses through its incredibly long seasons, which last for centuries.
>
> The trilogy consists of the books Helliconia Spring (published in 1982), Helliconia Summer (1983), and Helliconia Winter (1985).

and

> Bone Fever is a human viral disease characterized by an extreme form of anorexia, an epidemic of which sweeps the world early in the great spring. Fat Death is a disease characterized by an extreme form of binge eating, an epidemic of which sweeps the world late in the great autumn.

Answer (score 2):

FROM HELLICONIA:

Bone fever and fat death
Bone Fever is a human viral disease characterized by an extreme form of anorexia, an epidemic of which sweeps the world early in the great spring. Fat Death is a disease characterized by an extreme form of binge eating, an epidemic of which sweeps the world late in the great autumn.

That is the book.